# I can't change materials

Tags: materials

I was making a scene in blender and I wanted to change the texture from "Material_1" to "Material_2". It lets me change it but when I go to rendered view the part looks the same. can someone please help me

[image][image]

Comment: Selecting a material from the Material Slot list doesn't actually apply it to faces

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Don't see how it's a duplicate. This is about 1 material, not about multiple materials.

Comment: The procedure is the same... the material has to be assigned.

Comment: @cegaton https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/549/duplicate-answer-vs-duplicate-question

Comment: @RayMairlot I understand it is not the same thing, but the OP is clearly confused what materials slots are and how materials are applied, and that answer explains both, and hopefully provides some insight on the proper workflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a material as part of the list of materials for an object does not mean that it is applied to it.

In edit mode, select the material you want to use, then select the faces where you want the material to be and press **Assign**

[image]