# Material are not being applied to the model

Tags: materials

I'm new to blender and hit a bug probably.

I checked the material/texture/rendered view but the material is not being applied. I also created a new project and tested with a simple cube and tried the voronoi texture. The texture doesn't seem to work while I successfully applied bevel. I have checked the documentation and saw some tutorials and the followed the same steps as the videos but the material won't work.

EDIT:

OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Using cycles render, it didn't work in blender render either.
I was using 2.76 when I posted the question upgraded to 2.79 and the issue persists.

I assume material will be applied when I left click or press enter by selecting a certain material. Here's a screenshot [image]

Comment: Hi, why don't  you start showing/explaining which renderer are you using, and how you set up materials? And which blender version/OS are you using?

Comment: edited the question

Comment: "I assume material will be applied when I left click or press enter" Not necessarily. As you have several materials it might happen another material is applied and not the one you expect. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Comment: But I don't have multiple materials.

Comment: You have. There are 2 materials - "Material.001" and "Material.003" (the latter currently selected) and empty material slot in the middle. Note - if material is selected from the list of present materials it doesn't mean it is applied to the model. Note also that faces can be assigned to material slot even if it's empty. So to avoid confusion remove empty slot and work with materials

Comment: "*I assume material will be applied when I left click or press enter by selecting a certain material.*" You assume wrong, this has been asked countless times, selecting materials from the list doesn't apply them, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84731/i-cant-change-materials