# Mesh will not show any material colors in the cycles quick render (shift + z)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, materials

I have a part of my mesh that is supposed to have an emission material (applied in cycles). I can see the material in the preview window on the side, and the nodes are the same as any other basic material (emission > material output), but it just won't appear when I do quick renders, in the way that the other materials appear. In fact, even if I apply a material that is being used in another part of the mesh, this one part will still only appear as gray.I also want to say that these are only materials, and I haven't added any UVs or anything to the other parts of the mesh, which display their materials just fine.

No emission
[image: (Image: No emission)]

No material appears at all
[image: (Image: No material appears at all)]

Comment: Are the materials assigned to the faces of the mesh? See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84731/i-cant-change-materials/84737#84737

Comment: Ah...they can't be applied in object mode, only in edit mode. I feel so dumb, I've been working too long without sleep. Thank you.